# Why doesn't build-dep work even when I have URIs in my sources list already?

Tags: apt

So I tried to install a package called RGL for the R statistics language.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep r-cran-rgl
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

Now I would have regarded that as a totally valid objection, but I had already added extra deb lines to my sources.list, which looks like this:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#/etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
#deb http://cran.cs.pu.edu.tw/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
```

This is not exactly crucial, because I was able to get RGL installed by an alternate command, namely

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

so I don't need build-dep to work right now.  But at some point in the future I will probably want to use build-dep syntax with apt-get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sources.list file contains binary URIs, but you need source URIs for `build-dep` to work. Add the following to your sources.list and then run `apt-get update`:

```
deb-src http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
```

Comment: To add to this explanation, deb binary package only list dependencies for running an program.  In order to learn the dependencies to build a program, the deb source package must be consulted.  Since you are installing build-deps its a good assumption you will build the package and will need source code, which is also contained in the deb source package.

Comment: Thats what I was saying (or trying to say) -- to justify why he needed a deb-src source to install binary packages (the build-deps).

Comment: That should greatly simplify some of my upcoming Linux projects.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When building python from source using the mercurial repo.

**Uncomment** the `deb-src` lines located in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

For example:

```
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
```

Ubuntu 16.10:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep python-defaults python3
```